# Create new xml attributes from other attribute

Tags: python, xml, parsing, tree, element

I have the following XML

```
<icim source="source">
  <object class="class_name" name="class_name">
    <attribute name="Type">
      <string>Type_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="DisplayName">
      <string>DisplayName</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Vendor">
      <string>Vendor_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Model">
      <string>Model_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Description">
      <string>Description_part1, Description_part2, Description_part3, Description_part4, Description_part5</string>
</attribute>
</object>
  <object class="class_name" name="class_name">
    <attribute name="Type">
      <string>Type_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="DisplayName">
      <DisplayName</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Vendor">
      <string>Vendor_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Model">
      <string>Model_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Description">
      <string>Description_part1, Description_part2, Description_part3, Description_part4, Description_part5</string>
</attribute>
</object>
.
.
.
</icim>
```

and I want to transform it using Python's Element Tree to this:

```
<icim source="source">
  <object class="class_name" name="class_name">
    <attribute name="Type">
      <string>Type_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="DisplayName">
      <string>DisplayName</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Vendor">
      <string>Vendor_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Model">
      <string>Model_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="String1">
      <string>Description_part1</string>
</attribute>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="String2">
      <string>Description_part2</string>
</attribute>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="String3">
      <string>Description_part3</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Description">
      <string>Description_part1, Description_part2, Description_part3, Description_part4, Description_part5</string>
</attribute>
</object>
  <object class="class_name" name="class_name">
    <attribute name="Type">
      <string>Type_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="DisplayName">
      <DisplayName</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Vendor">
      <string>Vendor_Name</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Model">
      <string>Model_Name</string>
</attribute>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="String1">
      <string>Description_part1</string>
</attribute>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="String2">
      <string>Description_part2</string>
</attribute>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="String3">
      <string>Description_part3</string>
</attribute>
    <attribute name="Description">
      <string>Description_part1, Description_part2, Description_part3, Description_part4, Description_part5</string>
</attribute>
</object>
.
.
.
</icim>
```

That is I want to extract the first three string parts from each Description element (the Description always has commas, so you can split the parts based on those) and create a new  attribute for each of  the first 3 Description parts. Thoughts?

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly is the problem? We can help you if you get stuck, but please don't just ask for "thoughts".

Answer (score 0):

Your xml and expected xml aren't well formed (`<DisplayName</string>` should be  `<string>DisplayName</string>`) but assuming it's fixed, and if I undertstand you correctly, the following should get you at least most of the way there:

```
from lxml import etree
display = """[your xml above, corrected]"""
doc = etree.XML(display)

objs = doc.xpath("//object")
for obj in objs:    
    news = obj.xpath('.//attribute[@ name="Description"]/string/text()')[0].split(',')[:3]
    counter=3 
    for new in reversed(news): #this list needs to be reversed to get the new elements into the xml in the correct order
        ins =  etree.fromstring(f'<attribute name="String{counter}">\n      <string>{new.strip()}</string>\n</attribute>\n')
        obj.insert(4,ins)    
        counter-=1 #same reason for counting in reverse
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output should your expected output.